Flex Ticket Schiphol to Leuven, can I refund, and should I use partially?
I bought a flexticket from SNCB international, travelling between Amsterdam Schiphol to Leuven, via Antwerpen. Travel date is today (August 15th 24).
However when I landed earlier it seems like the connection between Schiphol and Antwerpen is not working. To go to Leuven, I was told to go through Brussel Noord via the SNCB intl app. I am already too tired to do that, so I took a flixbus to Antwerpen.
Is it possible to refund the flixticket? Technically I can still travel to Leuven (but takes much longer). Also, do I need to contact both SNCB and NS?
Also, I still have to take a train from Antwerpen to Leuven, but is only ~7euros due to the youth ticket. Should I purchase this extra ticket separately, so that the flex ticket remains purely unused?
Edit: I ended up purchasing a separate ticket between Antwerpen and Leuven. I have contacted SNCB, since I purchased the ticket from them, but have not received a reply.

Hope you found a resolution in the end, if so, would you care to include it as an answer to your own question to help any future travellers with a similar problem?

@SaaruLindestøkke still in process. Gave an update

Why did you buy a flixbus ticket to Antwerpen when you had a train ticket that would get you to Antwerpen?

You cannot get a refund for a ticket afterwards, as there is usually no way to prove that you have not used the ticket.
Furthermore you could have used your ticket on an earlier train to Leuven. Trains from Schiphol to Antwerpen run hourly, and from there to Leuven they run hourly as well. And your ticket, being a flex ticket, was valid on all of those trains.
There was thus no need to buy an extra ticket Antwerpen Leuven as well, as you already had one valid there.
Those trains from Schiphol continue to Brussel, where you also have frequent connections to Leuven. And sometimes that route is faster, which is why the B-Europe app suggested that route. The thing to do would have been just to take that train.
So there is no reason why you should be entitled to a refund.

The connection between Schiphol and Antwerpen was broken. A 2h30 trip became 5 ish, as I had to wait about an hour for a train in Leuven.

2h30 if I go via Antwerpen (the original plan), and 5h via Bxl Noord.
